# Проверка автризации в urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Хочу полностью закрыть сайт для не авторизованных.. Подскажите что не так?

Django==1.9.6 urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

if User.is_authenticated:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$', views.home_page),
    ]
else:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Comment: urls.py выполняется ОДИН раз при запуске сервера ДО какого-либо приёма запросов от неавторизованных

Comment: И кроме того, во-первых, is_authenticated - это не атрибут, это метод, а во-вторых, User - это класс, для вызова метода надо сначала создать объект этого класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы "пометить" какой-то url или группу url'ов, как требующие авторизации, можно воспользоваться декоратором:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
...
url(r"^select2/fields/auto.json$", login_required(AutoResponseView.as_view()), name="django_select2-json"),
...
]
```

Если хочется закрыть весь сайт от неавторизованных пользователей, то стоит использовать middleware. Например, таким:

**middleware.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from re import compile

EXEMPT_URLS = [compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [compile(expr) for expr in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Его надо прописать в MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    appname.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware,
    ...
]
```